# PHP echo date and number from query

Tags: php, database, mysqli, echo

Hi I have trying to learn php by writing little web app for showing me sales data. I have got a query which i now works as i have tested it but i want it to echo the datematched and the number of rows/results found with that date. This is what I have so far

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM matched WHERE datematched IN (
    SELECT datematched FROM matched GROUP BY datematched HAVING count(*) > 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "['";
 echo "" . $date['datematched'] . "', ";
  echo "" . $num_rows . "],";

   }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I know i am doing something wrong here. ryan

EDIT:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM matched WHERE datematched IN (
    SELECT datematched FROM matched GROUP BY datematched HAVING count(*) > 1");


 echo "['";
 echo " 16/08/2013 ', ";
  echo "12345}],";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Okay i have just checked my echo and they work i put in some data so all i need is to find a way of getting the information of the datematched that has been found and then the number of rows that has been found with that. Thanks Ryan

Comment: What is setting $date ? do you mean $row['datematched'] ?

Comment: What does your table schema look like?

Comment: Try `echo $row['datematched']` and `echo $result->$num_rows`

Comment: use $row instead of $date

Comment: @Anigel, Thanks for noticing that i changed it and it made no change

Comment: What is in your database as some of the answers you have been given should certainly have worked

Comment: there are 6 columns 1 of which is called datematched. in the other columns there are company names and numbers in the date matched field are dates Not sure why they are not working

Comment: are you trying to create a JSON string manually?

Comment: Seems to me you need to go back to basics and explain exactly what you mean by not working

Comment: I have a query which i know works. All I want to do is echo the datematched and the number of rows that have the same datematched. When i try my code above it does not show anything and whenever i have tried other people solutions it also behaves the same way.

Comment: I have updated my question with a piece of code that echos just some numbers but i want it to echo the datematched and the number of rows assigned with that value.

Comment: Your query doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Okay what do i need to do to make it do what i want

Comment: First, get yourself a query that definitely returns both date and  number. It looks like you will need a join instead of sub-query.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks i will look in to this

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to make an adjustment to your query, so that it has the number of rows your expecting.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT datematched, COUNT(*) as num_rows "
       . "FROM matched GROUP BY datematched HAVING num_rows > 0");
```

then you can display the data as follows

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['datematched'] . ",";
 echo $row['num_rows'];
}
```

Comment: I don't even think you need the HAVING clause as it is not going to select rows with a count of 0

Answer (score 0):

if your sql query is perfect then you should write like this wayt

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

  {
  echo "['";
 echo "" . $row['datematched'] . "', ";
  echo  "" . $row['num_rows'] . "', ";

   }
```

please set your column as you got in your mysql query.

Comment: Hi @liyakat I have just tried this and it did not work. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT datematched FROM matched GROUP BY datematched");
$num=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($num>1)
{ 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM matched");
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '['; echo $row['datematched']; echo $num_rows; echo ']';
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @chirag ode Sorry but this did not work it didn't even make my page load.

Comment: Hi @Chirag ode, i have tried your updated code and it did not work i will post my structure in my question in a moment